# Why does IE full justify the text?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On my company's website ([www.dmacorporation.com](http://www.dmacorporation.com) we have a section on the first page that isn't displaying properly.  The *IDM Integrated Database Management System* is appearing as fully justified, but it is supposed to be left justified.  I have fixed a local copy to show up properly in other browsers by changing the in-page css to include a text-align for the a.NormalHL class, but IE doesn't acknowledge this.  Can anyone tell me what would need to be changed to get this left justified instead of full justified?  Thanks.

p.s. don't mind the mess, we're only allowed to fix the code right now :(

Comment: Are you not able to edit the p tag surrounding the a tag? all the p tag needs is a class that has text-align: left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is line 126 from the default.css file:

```
P {font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; text-align:justify;}
```

Since that link is a child of the following:

```
<p class="WhiteLink Style10" align="center">
```

it inherits the justified text-align.  If you change line 126 to say:

```
P {font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; text-align:left;}
```

that should fix it.  If, for some reason, you cannot access default.css, you can always add this line of code in the css file you have access to:

```
P {text-align:left !important;}
```

Comment: Save the use of "!important" for only the most extreme of situations and using with fear and grave reservation.  That declaration interferes with inheritance, which makes maintenance of large CSS extremely convoluted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I guess I was completely mentally blind last week as I wasn't paying attention at all to the settings for the p tag.  Inline CSS to overwrite this one case made it possible (the boss wants full justification by default).

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) makes it pretty easy:

[image: Firebug]

Change "justify" to "left" and you're done.